# How to pass a selected value from a TKinter listbox to a main TKinter script

Tags: python, tkinter

I can populate my listbox with a list of files, I want to select one file and return it to the main TKinter script for processing. I am here at the moment......

'''cwd = os.getcwd()

decrypt_this_file=" "

def display_files():

```
window = Tk()
window.geometry('350x250+400+200')
window.title( 'Secrets Available' )

frame = Frame( window )

listbox = Listbox(frame)
for name in os.listdir(cwd):
    if re.search("encrypted$",name):  
        listbox.insert('end', name)

def dialog() :
    global decrypt_this_file
    box.showinfo( 'Selection' , 'Your Choice: ' + \
    listbox.get( listbox.curselection() ) )
    
    decrypt_this_file=listbox

def close_box():
    window.destroy()
    

btn = Button( frame, text = 'Select\nfile to\ndecrypt', command=dialog )
btn2 = Button( frame, text = 'Close', command=close_box )

btn.pack( side = RIGHT , padx = 5 )
btn2.pack( side = RIGHT, padx=5)
listbox.pack( side = LEFT )
frame.pack( padx = 30, pady = 30 )

window.mainloop()'''
```

but nothing is getting passed. Not sure where to go next. All help gladly received, Diolch yn fawr!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your code should be decrypt_this_file=listbox.get( listbox.curselection() )

Comment: Diolch o galon Eric, hwnna beth o'n i eisiau, chi'n da iawn. / Thanks Eric, that's what I wanted, well done